# How to make JQuery's droppable element to accept one and just one draggable element from a bunch of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a project, is like a calendar to make appoinments for diferent doctors in a hospital. I have a table and in each "td" is a droppable element. I have some "div's" whose are draggable elements. What I want to do is to drag elements to the droppables, but not having more han one per "td". The divs have different classes because they're in different color. Than you!

Comment: Show us your markup and the javascript you've already written

Comment: Post your code, or provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the limited information about your particular case, here's a suggestion:
Once a draggable is dropped onto the droppable, remove the ability for both the draggable and droppable to be futher dragged and dropped in the drop event:

http://jsfiddle.net/96ecc/

```
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
         $(this).droppable( "destroy" );
          event.ui.draggable("destory");
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpfull. Next time I'll add more information.